# AttributeError: 'MigrationLoader' object has no attribute 'items' django migration error

Tags: python, django, migration, django-migrations

i had sqlite conflict error, after merging i got another sqlite regex match error so i deleted migrations and sqlite files. when i run 'python manage.py makemigrations' i got this error and i don't know how to solve.

```
  File "/media/alirezaara/60BC049CBC046EBA1/mkpython_course/projects/blog/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/alirezaara/60BC049CBC046EBA1/mkpython_course/projects/blog/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/media/alirezaara/60BC049CBC046EBA1/mkpython_course/projects/blog/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/media/alirezaara/60BC049CBC046EBA1/mkpython_course/projects/blog/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/media/alirezaara/60BC049CBC046EBA1/mkpython_course/projects/blog/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/media/alirezaara/60BC049CBC046EBA1/mkpython_course/projects/blog/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/media/alirezaara/60BC049CBC046EBA1/mkpython_course/projects/blog/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/alirezaara/60BC049CBC046EBA1/mkpython_course/projects/blog/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 125, in handle
    for app, names in conflicts.items()
AttributeError: 'MigrationLoader' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this -      `variable_name = MigrationLoader.items()`

Here **items can be method rather than attribute**

Comment: i never have been use MigrationLoader in my codes. i just wanted to add feed in my django project. my feed code is:                                                                                     `class PostFeed(Feed):
    title = 'my blog'
    link = reverse_lazy('post:post-list')
    description = 'my blog feed'

    def items(self):
        return Post.published.all()[:5]

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title

    def item_description(self, item):
        return truncatewords(item.text, 30)`